# Angular 2 upload Image button is refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, button, angular2-forms, page-refresh

I have a html form with two buttons on it:-

[1] One button is used to upload an image file (.jpg)
[2] and the second one is to submit the form.

The problem is that the upload image button seems to be refreshing the page after the method for uploading the image has completed. Below is my html:-

```
<div class="m-b-18px">
  <div class="col-m-12">
    <a (click)="readRecipes()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Read Recipes
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <form [formGroup]="create_recipe_form" (ngSubmit)="createRecipe()">
      <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <td>
            Name
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="name" formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control" required />
            <div *ngIf="create_recipe_form.get('name').touched && create_recipe_form.get('name').hasError('required')"
              class="alert alert-danger">Name is required
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            Description
          </td>
          <td>
            <textarea name="description" formControlName="description" class="form-control" required>

            </textarea>
            <div *ngIf="create_recipe_form.get('description').touched && create_recipe_form.get('description').hasError('required')"
              class="alert alert-danger">
              Description is required
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            Image
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="selectFile" id="selectFile" type="file" class="form-control btn btn-success" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="uploadImage($event)" value="Upload Image">Upload Image</button>
            <input type='hidden' id='image_id' name='img_id' value="6" formControlName="image_id" />
          </td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!create_recipe_form.valid">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Create
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

My code for the uploadImage method is below:-

```
 uploadImage(e) {
    let files = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector('#selectFile').files;
    let formData = new FormData();
    let file = files[0];

    formData.append('selectFile', file, file.name);

    this._imageService.uploadImage(formData)
      .subscribe(
        image => {
          console.log(image);
          this.addImageIdToHtml(image)
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
        },
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }
```

As soon as the above method has finished running the page appears to refreshing causing my app to go back to the land page. This is not the behaviour I want. What I actually want is the form page to be retained until the Submit form button is pressed. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Use *div* tags instead of *form* tag.

---

Change the button type as *button*.

```
<button type="button">Upload Image</button>
```

---

Modify the code as follows.

```
<div class="m-b-18px">
  <div class="col-m-12">
    <a (click)="readRecipes()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Read Recipes
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div [formGroup]="create_recipe_form" (ngSubmit)="createRecipe()">
      <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <td>
            Name
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="name" formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control" required />
            <div *ngIf="create_recipe_form.get('name').touched && create_recipe_form.get('name').hasError('required')"
              class="alert alert-danger">Name is required
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            Description
          </td>
          <td>
            <textarea name="description" formControlName="description" class="form-control" required>

            </textarea>
            <div *ngIf="create_recipe_form.get('description').touched && create_recipe_form.get('description').hasError('required')"
              class="alert alert-danger">
              Description is required
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            Image
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="selectFile" id="selectFile" type="file" class="form-control btn btn-success" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="uploadImage($event)" value="Upload Image">Upload Image</button>
            <input type='hidden' id='image_id' name='img_id' value="6" formControlName="image_id" />
          </td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" [disabled]="!create_recipe_form.valid">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Create
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not upload files on Angular folders like (Assets) , cuz it will recompile every time new file added to Angular environment and that will cause you the page refreshment you didn't want.

Comment: This is the right solution. And it's one of these abstract implicit things one has to learn about Angular. It's also the fault of the watchers which are pretty bad. Disable the live reload if you need to put files in the assets folder

Answer (score 0):

If you are using button tag inside the form tag, add `type="button"` inside the button tag.

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

This will work perfectly

Comment: If you look at my html u can see that I have already done this:- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="uploadImage($event)" value="Upload Image">Upload Image</button>

Comment: The second button type is submit.